# Unable to find next record from recordset

Tags: vba, recordset

I am coding a search function to search for the record based on the selected field and value entered. I am using findfirst and findnext method, however, I am only able to find the first record and unable to get the find next functioning. Below is my code:

```
     Set rs = Forms("tabel1").Recordset.Clone

        sField = Switch(field = "IDs", "ID", field = "First Name", "FirstName", field = "Last Name", "LastName", field = "Email Address", "Email", True, "OTHER")

        If count > 1 Then
            rs.FindNext (sField & " = '" & value & "'")
            If rs.NoMatch Then
                MsgBox ("There are no more instances of '" & value & "' in" & sField & ".")
                count = 1
                rs.Close
                Exit Sub
            Else
                ' Find the next instance
                Forms("tabel1").Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
            End If
        Else
            rs.FindFirst (sField & " = '" & value & "'")
              If rs.NoMatch Then
                MsgBox ("Cannot find '" & value & "' in" & sField & "; Please enter a valid value.")
                rs.Close
                Exit Sub
              Else
                Forms("tabel1").Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
            End If
        End If
        Forms("tabel1").Refresh
        rs.Close
        Else
        MsgBox ("Please enter a valid search value")
        Me.txtValue.SetFocus
    End If
    Else
    Me.txtValue.SetFocus
    Me.txtValue.Text = ""
    answer = MsgBox("Please select a search field and enter a search value.", vbExclamation, "Missing Fields")
    Me.ComboSearchField.SetFocus
End If
```

Please tell me what am I missing or doing wrongly. Sorry but I am quite rusty in VBA. 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you receiving an error or is it just not entering the Find Next portion of your if statement?  Where are you setting a value for count?  It should probably be something like `count = rs.recordCount`

Comment: @Zaider, I did not receive any error. It just not entering the find next statement. The count is not mark how many times the user click the "Find Next" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not actually looping in the code provided so you will always hit `FindFirst` on the first pass and never the come back around to it the `FindNext` statement.  Try something like this:

```
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If rs.AbsolutePosition = 1 Then
            'do something to first record set
        Else
            'do something else...
        End If
    Loop
```

---

The `Do Until rs.EOF` will only loop when you have a record set returned.

Comment: Thanks for your tips on 'rs.AbsolutePosition'. I dimmed a currentPos variable and assign that to next loop and it works! Thank you.